# Applying bootstrap grid isn't working as desired

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I am trying to achieve,

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far,

```
<ul class="list-group" style="margin:20px">

  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="#" class="row">
      <span class="col-md-10" style="font-size: 16px;">Item 1</span>
      <span class="col-md-1 glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
      <span class="pull-right btn-group col-md-1">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Delete</button>
    </span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="list-group-item">
    <a href="#" class="row">
      <span class="col-md-10" style="font-size: 16px;">Item 2</span>
      <span class="col-md-1 glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
      <span class="pull-right btn-group col-md-1">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Delete</button>
    </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/EpG7x/524/

**Problem**

- Not able to make bootstrap grids work
- Not sure how to use bootstrap grids by moving out my edit/delete button from "a" tag
- Not sure how to add full height border to left of my button groups as list-group-item has     /* padding: 10px 15px; */ which I don't want to loose

Comment: Why are you putting a submit button inside a link?

Comment: @Quentin It's not requirement, they will have there own click events, I am happy to take them out of "a" -- I think that would be the best

Comment: Since HTML doesn't allow a button to be a descendant of an anchor: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Is that you want?

Just wrap the anchor tag only for the text.

```css
.list-group-item .col-xs-8 ,.list-group-item .col-xs-4,
.list-group-item .col-md-8 ,.list-group-item .col-md-4{
  border:1px solid gray;
  height:100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.list-group-item,.row{
  padding:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-group" style="margin:20px">
  <li class="list-group-item row">
    <a href="#" class="">
      <span class="pull-left col-md-8 col-xs-8">
      <span class="col-md-10" style="font-size: 16px;">Item 1</span>
      <span class="col-md-1 pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
      </span>
    </a>
    <span class="pull-right btn-group  col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Delete</button>
    </span>

  </li>

  <li class="list-group-item row">
    <a href="#" class="">
      <span class="pull-left  col-md-8 col-xs-8">
      <span class="col-md-10" style="font-size: 16px;">Item 2</span>
      <span class="col-md-1 pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
      </span>
    </a>
    
    <span class="pull-right btn-group  col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Delete</button>
    </span>

  </li>
</ul>
```